# Geometry nodes: number of distributed points per face

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to get the number of distributed points per face. In the following node tree I get the number of points for face 0, but how to calculate this for each face (face_index in this example) of the geometry?

[image]

Comment: Do you need the information in the face domain of the original object, or in the point domain of the distributed points?

Comment: @quellenform: tnx! :) I need it in de face domain of the original object. Actually I wasn't aware of that but your answer below showed me (thank you for this also ;-)).

Comment: ...All right, that's what I thought ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the number of points per face, the node `Accumulate Field` helps you.

If you feed the *Group Index* of this node with the index of the original face, you can sum up the number of points.

[image]

Note, this example counts the number of points in the point domain of the distributed points. So for each point you get the additional information how many points were distributed in the same face.

---

However, if you want to get the number of points in the face domain of the original geometry, you would have to query the values from the face domain.

Here the number of faces does not correspond to the number of distributed points, so you would first have to set the positions of the points to the positions of the original faces, and then use `Sample Nearest` and `Sample Index` to get the values. By comparing the positions of the points and the faces, you simultaneously prevent counting the points of another face.

This could look something like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Comment: Great! Tnx a lot :-)